# AUCTeX: prevent indentation inside commands

Tags: indentation, auctex

I am not a fan of the way AUCTeX indent LaTeX code.  Some time ago I [asked for help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862391/prevent-auctex-indentation-with-fill-paragraph) in disabling indentation.

The solution provided there handles the large majority of my needs, but fails to prevent indentation of text inside brackets, such as for \footnote{text} or \textbf{something bold}.  More specifically, if I have some text like this

```
Here is a paragraph which you should 
pretend\footnote{some stuff} has much
longer lines.
```

and then fill the paragraph, I often get something like the following

```
Here is a paragraph which you 
should pretend\footnote{some
  stuff} has much longer
lines.
```

I don't like the way the contents of the \footnote command are indented.  Is there a simple way to disable this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the manual often helps: this is controlled by [`TeX-brace-indent-level`](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Indenting).

> User Option: `TeX-brace-indent-level`
>
> Number of spaces to add to the indentation for each `{` not matched by a `}`.

Set it to 0 in your init file:

```lisp
(setq TeX-brace-indent-level 0)
```